# Solaris projects id and group id should be the same?

Tags: solaris

I had defined a project under group mqm

```
group.mqm
    projid : 100
    users  : mqm
    groups : mqm
    attribs: process.max-file-descriptor=(basic,10000,deny)
             project.max-sem-ids=(priv,1024,deny)
             project.max-shm-ids=(priv,1024,deny)
             project.max-shm-memory=(priv,4294967296,deny)
```

the group id of mqm is 113 if I do a listing of /etc/group

Should the projid be the same as the actual gid of mqm group? ie, 113, instead of 100? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my project ID set to the same as the group for oracle, but as  you don't need to have them match for it to take effect.

I just do it so I know that project belongs to that group